# KVM - is VEPA "software implementation" of SR-IOV?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, sr-iov

I'm reading about options to improve CPU usage and in general networking performance between VMs. I knew about bridged networking and pci-e passthrough, as well as SR-IOV however now I found out about VEPA interface attachment method and it's quite interesting. From what it looks like to me - VEPA `macvtap` interface works basically the same as SR-IOV `vf` interfaces (at least with Intel SR-IOV implementation) but doesn't seem to require SR-IOV support. Is it correct? Of course i believe it suffers from lower performance as it's still less hardware based solution but apart from that they look the same. Are there some other caveats I missed?

Answer (score 1):

VEPA is about having a switch supporting extensible virtual interfaces. More about scalability than performance. If you are looking to utilize macvtap and increase performance, have a look at VMFEX (if you have Cisco blades) or start looking at things like DPDK